# Error installing tesseract Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, tesseract, python-tesseract

I've tried numerous methods to install Tesseract but I just can't seem to get it working. I'm on a mac and this is the error I keep getting

```
    txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng')
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 161, in image_to_string
    config=config)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 94, in run_tesseract
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue with tesseract?

Comment: What is `image`? A filepath? Does that exist?

Comment: Or `pytesseract` is trying to run `tesseract`? Your question never shows installing tesseract, so what is **that** error?

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda does have `conda` Tesseract package available. Use below command to install it and try again.

```
conda install -c brown-data-science tesseract=3.05.00
```

If you need the latest vesrion `Tesseract 4.00.00alpha`, you may refer to [github](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki#mac-os-x) on the installation instructions. If you don't have `Xcode` or `Homebrew` installed, check [this](http://benschmidt.org/dighist13/?page_id=129) to install it.